# parse JsonArray in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

How to parse this jsonarray "Images" ??

I parse this json ,, but i can't get "Images"
the Jsonarray "data" inside it elements , inside every element array of images  >>>>

this is the response 
[image: Json]

this is my code

```
                JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);

                JSONArray newsJsonArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("data");
                final List <AndroidVersion> newsList = new ArrayList <AndroidVersion>();

                newsImages = new ArrayList<String>();
                newsids = new ArrayList<String>();
                newsnames = new ArrayList<String>();
                newshotelsid = new ArrayList<String>();
                newscontents = new ArrayList<String>();
                newstimesto = new ArrayList<String>();
                newscost = new ArrayList<String>();
                newstimesfrom = new ArrayList<String>();
                newscountry = new ArrayList<String>();
                newscity = new ArrayList<String>();
                newstype = new ArrayList<String>();
                newsImages = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int j = 0; j < newsJsonArray.length(); j++) {
                        AndroidVersion news = new AndroidVersion();
                        if (newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).has("id")) {
                            newsids.add(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("id"));
                        }
                        if (newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).has("name")) {
                            news.setName(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("name"));
                            newsnames.add(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("name"));

                        }
                        if (newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).has("desc")) {
                            news.setdesc(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("desc")
                                    .replaceAll("<p>", "").replaceAll("<\\/p>\\r\\n", "").replaceAll("&nbsp;", ""));
                            newscontents.add(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("describtion"));
                        }

                        if (newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).has("country")) {
                            news.setcountry(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("country"));
                            newscountry.add(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("country"));
                        }

                        if (newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).has("city")) {
                            news.setcity(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("city"));
                            newscity.add(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("city"));
                        }

                        if (newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).has("date_from")) {
                            news.setdate_from(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("date_from"));
                            newstimesfrom.add(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("date_from"));
                        }
                        if (newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).has("date_to")) {
                            news.setdate_to(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("date_to"));
                            newstimesto.add(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("date_to"));
                        }
                        if (newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).has("num persons")) {
                            news.sethotel_id(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("num persons"));
                            newshotelsid.add(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("num persons"));
                        }
                        if (newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).has("price")) {
                            news.setprice(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("price"));
                            newscost.add(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("price"));
                        }
                        if (newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).has("images")) {
                            news.setImage(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("images"));
                            newsImages.add(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("images"));
                        }
                        newsList.add(news);
                    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: did you get url of images in list??

Comment: Images is an array, not a string. You need another for loop

Comment: Also, I would strongly recommend that you make `newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j)` its own variable rather than constantly getting it over and over again

Comment: Then, what's `num persons`? That isn't even in your data

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using Gson to parse it.

Create a response object with structure matching the json response. Then you can use the single object without having to create it down into parts.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
 if (newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).has("images")) {
     news.setImage(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("images"));
     newsImages.add(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("images"));
 }
```

to:

```
if(newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getJSONArray("images") != null) {
    JSONArray jArray = newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getJSONArray("images");
    for (int k=0; k<jArray.length(); k++) {
         news.setImage(jArray.getString(k));
         newsImages.add(jArray.getString(k));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, should be getJSONArray instead of getJsonArray. I have updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct string object from JSONArray like below:

```
JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("images");

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

String image = array.getString(i);

}
```